# The images subdomain does not work on my wordpress site when i use https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, dns, cpanel

I have https on with a valid certificate.  I am trying to put images on a subdomain, which the certificate is also valid for.  it is a wordpress site.  It is hosted in cpanel.  It works in http, but not https.
ie this works http://images.mavencomputers.com.au/Logo.png 
but this has a 404 https://images.mavencomputers.com.au/Logo.png

Comment: I resolved this issue.  the host had installed the certificate on only the root domain, but this certificate should have been installed separately on every subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your siteurl is starting with https:// in you wp_options table

You need to replace the

```
<img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" alt="image">
```

to

`<img src="//example.com/image.jpg" alt="image">` so They will load that resource with whatever protocol the current page is.

> Take a database backup first

and then update wp_posts

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET    post_content = ( Replace (post_content, 'src="http://', 'src="//') )
WHERE  Instr(post_content, 'jpeg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'jpg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'gif') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'png') > 0;
```

And another to catch single-quoted ones, just in case:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET   post_content = ( Replace (post_content, "src='http://", "src='//") )
WHERE  Instr(post_content, 'jpeg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'jpg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'gif') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'png') > 0;
```